# Cant compile project from github because error in wdm.h file

Tags: kernel, driver, wdk

I'm trying to compile a project i found in github but it keeps giving me error with the file wdm.h which project uses because it uses WDK.

I tried to reinstall sdk and wdk and even Visual Studio but it keeps giving me this error no matter version of Visual Studio and SDK/WDK i use

[Compilation Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEnEu.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here we expect the error message in the **question post** as **text**, not as *image*. Please, (re-)read [ask] and [edit] your post accordingly.